# How to list all categories with the books associated with each of them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need some help please, I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails. I am building a digital library and I would like to list all the Categories for the digital library with the books for each category under them.

I would like it to be this way:

**Category Name**

- Book A
- Book B

**Category Name**

- Book C
- Book D

The relationship between the Category and Books are

**Category Model**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :books
end
```

**Book Model**

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**Categories controller**

```
def index
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @books = Book.all
end
```

**Categories view**

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <% Book.category.each do |book| %>
     <%= book.name %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I really don't know how to go about it, I have been running into errors.

**Please any form of support will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Categories controller

```
def index
  @categories = Category.includes(:books).all
end
```

#### Categories view

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= category.name %>
    <% category.books.each do |book| %>
      <%= book.name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### Categories view for Book Names with Links

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= category.name %>
    <% category.books.each do |book| %>
      <%= link_to book.name, book %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**N/B:** Use this if only you want to add links to the book names

Comment: Please, note that you can improve performance if you avoid the *N+1* queries by including `books` in the main query: `@categories = Category.includes(:books).all`

Comment: @imechemi, this answer worked. However, the category name output was missed, I just edited the answer to add it. Please confirm the edit so that I can mark the answer as **accepted**. Thank you **Imechemi** and **CAmador** for your immense assistance.

Comment: @PromisePreston Mark it as answered if this is done.